# Is there a symbol to mean "$x$ fits completely $v$ times in $y$"?

Tags: notation, education

Is there a simpler way to write "$x$ fits *completely* $v$ times in $y$," i.e. is there a mathematical symbol or way to write for example:

"32 fits 0 times *completely* in 4" or for example "32 fits 1 time *completely* in 40" more compactly?

Is there a symbol (preferably not too specific to any particular mathematical field) that could replace the text in my two examples above?

Comment: How about $\lfloor4/32\rfloor=0$ or $ \lfloor40/32\rfloor=1$, where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is greatest integer function?

Comment: $\left\lfloor \dfrac{40}{32}\right\rfloor = 1$ meanwhile $\left\lfloor\dfrac{16}{3}\right\rfloor = 5$, etc...

Comment: How many times does $0$ fit in $1$ ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe a complex infinity amount of times? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=floor(1%2F0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $x\neq 0$ You can use floor value of the division:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{y}{x}\right\rfloor=v$$

For example:

> $5$ fits completely $6$ times in $32$
>   $$\left\lfloor\frac{32}{5}\right\rfloor=6$$

Comment: Thank you @Jaroslaw Matlak, I had completely forgotten this one